# Build Read The Docs documentation from docs folder created with sphinx

Tags: python, authentication, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, google-earth-engine

I have made a python package (https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools) that depends entirely on Google Earth Engine Python API. Although the *earthengine-api* package is locally installed, to get full and real access to objects you need to authenticate in a simple way:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
```

but in order to make it work you have to

> *authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running earthengine authenticate*

The package work fine for me and all users that can authenticate. So, I built the documentation using sphinx, which looks really nice (http://geetools.readthedocs.io). The problem is that in my environment builds perfect, but in read the docs doesn't because it cannot authenticate in their environment, so the documentation doesn't build correctly.

This is read the doc's log:

> python
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/geetools/envs/latest/bin/sphinx-build
>   -T -E -b readthedocs -d _build/doctrees-readthedocs -D language=en . _build/html

```
Running Sphinx v1.5.6
making output directory...
loading translations [en]... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [readthedocs]: targets for 7 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 7 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 14%] Documentation
reading sources... [ 28%] Introduction
reading sources... [ 42%] cloud_mask
try n° 0 ERROR: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
```

I don't want to put my credentials inside code, so, my question:

is there a way to just 'upload' the *docs* folder I built locally to read the docs? or I just have to use another hosting provider?

I read http://dont-be-afraid-to-commit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html and found that

> you don’t want to commit your rendered files, just the source files

Comment: Have a look at GitHub Pages https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/

Comment: Thank you @StevePiercy, that was one of the options I had at first, but I dropped it because read the docs seemed a bit better, but it was superfluous, I'll give GitHub Pages a try!